# How do I declare a function that takes *any* block/closure as parameter?

Tags: swift, closures

I want to pass *any* block around as a parameter, without wanting to know the precise block parameter/return type.

```
func myFunc(block:(xxx) -> yyy) -> AnyObject {
...
}
```

So `xxx` in my code should match any number of parameters (including none) of any type. And `yyy` could be anything from `void` to `AnyObject` to an `NSObject`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a generic function:

```
func myFunc<A,B>(block:A -> B) -> AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that in Swift. [Function Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1100) are defined by their parameters and return types and there is no general function type. Functions also don't conform to Any or AnyObject, so you also can't use those either.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift it's still possible to use the Selector. Maybe you can achieve what you want using that. See sample below:

```
func myFunc(selector:Selector) -> AnyObject {
    self.performSelector(selector)
}
func someSelector() -> String {
    return "test"
}
var result: AnyObject = myFunc(Selector("someSelector"))
```